# Import new database after category description not showing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, import

*Hello I have import new database and category description no showing. Description.phtml no working. But in old Database everything is good.*

***is that import Database issue?***

***Where i find error in database ?***

Comment: can you explain in detail

Comment: first can you please check with category_entity_text, category_entity_varchar

Comment: @RajMohanR In old database everything is good. I can change in category page description. When I download database from server i can't add category description (is not display). I also have this problem on the server

Comment: @RajMohanR  Debuuger don't stop in description.phtml

Comment: @Tomalo did you do Re-indexing?

Comment: @SavanPatel Yes